# Dynamic filename for SQL Server backups?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup, variables, filenames

How can you insert the date in the filename (a dynamic filename) used in a T-SQL backup script?  Using SQL Enterprise Manager to create and schedule a backup job, I'd like to edit the T-SQL created to change the filename of the backed up database to be dbname_date.bak (i.e. northwind_5-1-2009.bak).  The next time the backup runs, it will be northwinds_new_date.bak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically what you want to do is declare a string variable, set it to the name and then append the date to the end of the variable.  then just use the variable where the name of the backup goes

```
declare @backupname nvarchar(100)
set @backupname = 'northwind_' + getdate() + '.bak'
```

something like that should work.  you might have to sat the getdate() to nvarchar.

Comment: Had to convert getdate() to MM-DD-YYYY using the CONVERT function and then it worked like a champ!!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you really want to know - don't reinvent the wheel.  Here's a fantastic script to automate backups that does what you're describing:

https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Very nice but it doesn't answer my question.  I will play around your script though...