# SQL Server .BAK creation default mask

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, vsdb

Currently, when SQL server creates a .BAK file (backing up a database) it is using a default mask such as 
DatabaseName-YearMonthDay-Time.bak

Is there a way to change this default?  i.e. Suppose I just want DatabaseName-YearMonthDay.bak (by default)

Thanks.

Some elaboration: I am using a Visual Studio database project and have checked the "Back up database before deployment" flag - which automatically generates a .bak file in the default backup location (so while I could probably make a stored proceudure, I like this option better) - I am guessing that it is not easy to do this (if even possible)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic filename for SQL Server backups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813248/dynamic-filename-for-sql-server-backups)

Comment: Similar (thank you), but I believe this to be more of a sql server setting: i.e. when you create a backup file in Management Studio it gives you a default name to use (as mentioned in original post)  - that thread is pertaining more to how to do it with T-SQL.  I am skeptical of being able to do this at all..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the GUI in SSMS to take the backups us a SQL script. If you use a SQL script you can fully customize the file names.

Here is an example script that puts Time, Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute and second into the backup file name:

```
--Script 1: Backup specific database

-- 1. Variable declaration

DECLARE @path VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @pathwithname VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @time DATETIME
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @hour VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @minute VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @second VARCHAR(2)

-- 2. Setting the backup path

SET @path = 'E:\Backup\'

-- 3. Getting the time values

SELECT @time   = GETDATE()
SELECT @year   = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy, @time)))
SELECT @month  = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(mm,@time),'00')))
SELECT @day    = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(dd,@time),'00')))
SELECT @hour   = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(hh,@time),'00')))
SELECT @minute = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(mi,@time),'00')))
SELECT @second = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(ss,@time),'00')))

-- 4. Defining the filename format

SELECT @name ='TestDatabase' + '_' + @year + @month + @day + @hour + @minute + @second

SET @pathwithname = @path + @namE + '.bak'

--5. Executing the backup command

BACKUP DATABASE [TestDatabase] 
TO DISK = @pathwithname WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```